# How to create permutations of multiple conditions (without long if condition)

Tags: python

I have several variables that I need to permute with each other.

Simple example with four variables: `UP`, `DOWN`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`:

```
#when variable UP is max
if UP > RIGHT > LEFT > DOWN or UP > RIGHT > DOWN > LEFT or UP > LEFT > RIGHT >DOWN or UP > LEFT > DOWN > RIGHT or UP > DOWN > RIGHT > LEFT or UP > DOWN > LEFT > RIGHT:
     some action ...

#when variable RIGHT is max
if RIGHT > UP > LEFT > DOWN or RIGHT > UP > DOWN > LEFT or RIGHT > LEFT > UP > DOWN or RIGHT > LEFT > DOWN > UP or RIGHT > DOWN > UP > LEFT or RIGHT > DOWN > LEFT > UP:
     some action ...

.
.
.
```

Is there any way to create permutations without so long if condition ?

Comment: `if UP > max([RIGHT, LEFT, DOWN]):`

Comment: You can determine the max of all four variables first, then check `if up == the_max: ...`

Comment: Alternatively, `if UP > RIGHT and UP > LEFT and UP > DOWN:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off finding which one is highest, and then making one or more decisions off of that:

```
maxIndex = 0
values = [UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT]
for curIndex in range(len(values))
    if values[curIndex] > values[maxIndex]:
        maxIndex = curIndex

if maxIndex == 0: #Up is highest
    ...
else if maxIndex == 1: #down is highest
    ...
else if...
```

There are always alternative approaches.  The if/elseif/elsif chain could be replaced with [a dictionary full of lamdas, or several other constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python).  There's probably a math library out there that has a "find the highest value and return its index" function out there.